# Как реализовать счётчик и input range?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать такое?
Есть input range ,нужно реализовать  точно такое уменьшение и увеличение как это он делает с value.Так как для value есть условия при котором счётчик должен плюсовать от 0 до 40 +10000 от 40 до 70 +100000 от 70 до 100 +1000000.У меня получилось это с первым диапазоном но в обратную сторону не могу понять как это сделать.Т.е с каждым значение от и до действует счётчик с определённым увеличение и так как и в обратную сторону уменьшение.Может кто-то сталкивался с таким? За ранее благодарю за любой  ответ.

```js
var range = document.getElementById('range');
var rangeValue = document.getElementById('rangeValue');
var inputRangeResult = document.getElementById('inputRangeResult');


function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 0;

  return function() {
    return currentCount = currentCount + 10000;
  };
}

var counter = makeCounter();


range.addEventListener('input',function(){
    rangeValue.innerHTML = range.value;
    if(range.value > 0 && range.value < 40){
        inputRangeResult.innerHTML = counter();
    }else if(range.value >= 40 && range.value <= 70){
        inputRangeResult.innerHTML = 100000;
    }else if(range.value > 70 && range.value <= 100){
        inputRangeResult.innerHTML = 1000000;
    }else{
        inputRangeResult.innerHTML = 1;
    }
});
```

```html
    <div class="wrap" style="max-width: 580px;">
        <input style="width: 100%;" id="range"  type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1">
    </div>

    <p id="rangeValue">1</p>
    <p id="inputRangeResult"></p>
```

https://codepen.io/Konoplitskiy/pen/pogPoNJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var res = 0;
var sub = range.value;

res += Math.min(sub, (40 - 0)) * 10000;
sub  = Math.max(sub -= (40 - 0), 0);

res += Math.min(sub, (70 - 40)) * 100000;
sub  = Math.max(sub -= (70 - 40), 0);

res += Math.min(sub, (100 - 70)) * 1000000;
//sub  = Math.max(sub -= (100 - 70), 0)

inputRangeResult.innerHTML = res;
```